# Problem trying to access networked location with C#

Tags: c#

I want to have access to a location in my laptop using C#, the explicit destination is

`"\\file\doc/"+ GetImageNameFromPLC()+".jpg"`

but I can not get this with C#, this is how it looks currently

```
            Uri serverUri = new Uri(@"\\file\doc/"+ GetImageNameFromPLC()+".jpg");
            WebClient request = new WebClient();

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
            try            {
                byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(serverUri.ToString());
                return newFileData;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            return new byte[0];
        }

        private string GetImageNameFromPLC()
        {
```

In the first line I get the error:
*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.*

Could you please advice how the string "\file\doc/"+ GetImageNameFromPLC()+".jpg" should be written? Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Why are you using WebClient with a shared folder???? Never mind the *invalid* path, `/` isn't allowed in Windows file names

Comment: If you want to read a file's contents, `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllBytes` are enough. The path is the same path you'd use in Windows Explorer

Comment: The method where the error occurs is likely `static` (we can't see that in the code given), so `GetImageNameFromPLC()` must be static, too

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is in the slash `/` in Windows UNC paths use `\` instead. And also you should not use WebClient to download files from network share. You can directly read text content from the server using System.IO.File.ReadAllText, and also we need to get the code of the function `GetImageNameFromPLC()` errors may also reside there. You should use `private static` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The method where the error occurs is likely `static` (we can't see that in the code given). You have two options now:

1. make `GetImageNameFromPLC()` static, too
2. create an instance of the class where the code is in (`var obj = new ...()`) and then call `obj.GetImageNameFromPLC()`.

Please note, that your code will likely still not work, even if it compiles.

1. You use hardcoded `/` instead of `\` in the path. Also check the return value of `GetImageNameFromPLC()` - if it returns `/` as well, you need to replace it.
2. `WebClient` will try to access stuff via HTTP protocol, but a network share uses SMB protocol instead. You can access network files like regular files on a local hard disk.
3. If you read the documentation, [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1) is not suggested for new development any more. You should use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) instead.